# PHP string to object name

Tags: php, string, oop

Ok I have a string...

```
$a_string = "Product";
```

and I want to use this string in a call to a object like this:

```
$this->$a_string->some_function();
```

How the dickens do I dynamically call that object?

(don't think Im on php 5 mind)

Comment: Have you tried that code?.. Also, `echo phpversion();` will show you if you're on PHP 5.

Comment: why dont you use call_user_func (or call_user_func_array)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you the code you want to use would be:

```
$a_string = "Product";
$this->$a_string->some_function();
```

This code implies a few things. A class called `Product` with the method `some_function()`. `$this` has special meaning, and is only valid **inside** a class definition. So another class would have a member of `Product` class.

So to make your code legal, here's the code.

```
class Product {
    public function some_function() {
        print "I just printed Product->some_function()!";
    }
}

class AnotherClass {

    public $Product;

    function __construct() {
        $this->Product = new Product(); 
    }

    public function callSomeCode() {
        // Here's your code!
        $a_string = "Product";
        $this->$a_string->some_function();
    }
}
```

Then you can call it with this:

```
$MyInstanceOfAnotherClass = new AnotherClass();
$MyInstanceOfAnotherClass->callSomeCode();
```

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have read this question differently from everyone else who's responded, but are you trying to use [variable variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: You need to be running PHP5 in order to do any method chaining. After that, what you have is perfectly legal.

Comment: But this isn't true. What you can't do in PHP4 is chaining method calls like this: `$obj->method1(10)->method2(42);` (that, and `public/private/static` properties and methods)

Comment: You do not need to be running PHP 5.x to do any object oriented programming. There is an OO model in older versions as well.

Answer (score 0):

In the code you've shown, it looks like you're trying to call a function from string itself. My guess is that you want to call a function from a class with the same name as that string, in this case "Product."

This is what that would look like:

```
$this->Product->some_function();
```

It seems you might instead be looking for something like this:

```
$Product = new Product();
$Product->some_function();
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if I got your intentions correctly...

```
$some_obj=$this->$a_string;
$some_obj->some_function();
```

Answer (score 0):

So you've got an object, and one of it's properties (called "Product") is another object which has a method called some_function().

This works for me (in PHP5.3):

```
<?PHP


class Foo {
     var $bar;
}

class Bar {
      function some_func(){
           echo "hello!\n";
      }
}

$f = new Foo();
$f->bar = new Bar();

$str = 'bar';

$f->$str->some_func(); //echos "hello!"
```

I don't have PHP4 around, but if it doesn't work there, you might need to use [call_user_func()](http://us.php.net/call_user_func) (or call_user_func_array() if you need to pass arguments to some_function()